# If else counting

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, machine-learning

How can I count this data after classifying it into correct_pred and wrong_pred?

```
stats_all_score.head()
```

```
class   score1  score2  score3
A       1.67    3.60    5.50
A       3.60    3.25    2.10
A       2.25    3.25    3.25
B       1.17    6.50    21.00
C       3.20    3.25    2.30
..      ..      ..      ..
```

```
    if (stats_all_score['class'] == 'A' and stats_all_score['score1'] <= 2.20) 
    or (stats_all_score['class'] == 'B' and stats_all_score['score2'] <= 2.20) 
    or (stats_all_score['class'] == 'C' and stats_all_score['score3'] <= 2.20):
        return correct_pred
    else:
        return wrong_pred
```

```
File "<ipython-input-16-ffc4cad0f64a>", line 3
    else
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to tell people what is the problem of your existing code?

Comment: Code doesn't match the error. You have some `else` statement that is not "`else:`"

Comment: if my if-else is wrong, is there any other way to count this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement check the result of one single condition, not the results of multiple conditions. You need to wrap your logic calculations with `()`.

```
if (condition1 or condition2 or condition3):
    return something
```

Comment: count of what? You need to elaborate what you are trying to do a little bit. Are you using any library such as numpy or pandas?

Comment: i need to count the number of correct_pred and wrong_pred using either numpy or pandas

Comment: `correct_pred +=1` and `return correct_pred`, is that what you are saying?